# VarSelLCM returns error but input variables seem to be factors and integer

Tags: r

I have this simple dataset

https://www.mediafire.com/file/ntmu0tvtpm73h2i/data.xlsx/file

```
library(readxl)
library(VarSelLCM)
data <- read_xlsx("C:/User/data.xlsx")

data$type <- as.factor(data$type)
data$T3 <-as.integer(data$T3)
data$T5 <-as.integer(data$T5)
data$T14 <-as.integer(data$T14)
data$T15 <-as.integer(data$T15)
data$T18 <-as.integer(data$T18)
data$T22 <-as.integer(data$T22)
```

When I run lapply(data, class)

I get

```
$`T3`
[1] "integer"

$T5
[1] "integer"

$T14
[1] "integer"

$T15
[1] "integer"

$T18
[1] "integer"

$T22
[1] "integer"

$type
[1] "factor"
```

So everything seems to be OK.

But when I run

```
res_with <- VarSelCluster(data, gvals = 1:4, nbcores = 1, crit.varsel = "BIC")
```

I get the Error

```
Error in VSLCMdataMixte(x) : 
  At least one variable is neither numeric, integer nor factor!
```

The problem perhaps could be that when I run

```
> print(typeof(data$type))
```

I get this:

```
[1] "integer"
```

So it seems that data$type is integer?? though I converted it to factor? And it indeed is a factor as shown by lapply??

But even if the data$type variable was integer, it should be correct for VarSelCluster, because it requires integer variables, this is totally confusing.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VarSelCluster requires data as a data.frame, so first you need to set `class(data)="data.frame"`